# Racket (play-sound) undefined

Tags: racket

I've just started playing around with racket and wanted to include a few sounds in a program so I found the `play-sound` procedure is in the `racket/gui/base` library but when included with the `2htdp/image` library as well I get this error

```
*module: identifier already imported from a different source in:
make-color
racket/gui/base
2htdp/image
```

I've got `play-sound` working fine just using `racket/gui` but it's undefined when using `2htdp` alone.

```
>(play-sound "sounds/smash.wav" #t)
 . . play-sound: undefined;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`only-in`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._only-in%29%29) to require only specific functions from a module. For example this evaluates without error:

```
#lang racket

(require 2htdp/image
         (only-in racket/gui/base play-sound))

(define (f)
  (play-sound "/path/to/file" #t))
```